# Confusion in using argparse in Python

Tags: python, argparse

I would like to execute a code which is accessible from this [link](https://github.com/0xabu/pdfannots.git).
The code objective is to read and extract the `pdf` annotation.

However, I am not sure how to direct the `pdf` file path using the argparse, which I suspect, should be the following `argparse`.

```
p.add_argument("input", metavar="INFILE", type=argparse.FileType("rb"),
                   help="PDF files to process", nargs='+')
```

Say, I know the absolute path of the pdf file is as follow;

```
C:\abc.pdf
```

Also, given that I still try to comprehend the code, so I would like to avoid re-enter the path C:\abc.pdf over and over again. Is there are way, I can temporary hard coded it within the `def parse_args()`

I have read several thread about this topic, however, still having difficulties in comprehend about this issue.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: Are you asking how to pass command-line arguments to a Python script? Or what argparse does? (It parses command-line arguments.) Or do you want an introduction to the idea of command-line arguments?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Weeble. Say, I am now try to understand the whole code. So, I would like to avoid re-enter the path C:\abc.pdf over and over again. Is there are way, I can temporary hard coded it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running pdfannots.py from the command prompt, then you do so as, e.g.,

```
python pdfannots.py C:\abc.pdf
```

If you want to run it over multiple PDF files, then you do so as, e.g.,

```
python pdfannots.py C:\abc.pdf D:\xyz.pdf E:\foo.pdf
```

If you really want to hard code the path, you'll have to edit pdfannots.py as follows:

```
def parse_args():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)

    # p.add_argument("input", metavar="INFILE", type=argparse.FileType("rb"),
                   # help="PDF files to process", nargs='+')

    g = p.add_argument_group('Basic options')
    g.add_argument("-p", "--progress", default=False, action="store_true",
                   help="emit progress information")
    g.add_argument("-o", metavar="OUTFILE", type=argparse.FileType("w"), dest="output",
                   default=sys.stdout, help="output file (default is stdout)")
    g.add_argument("-n", "--cols", default=2, type=int, metavar="COLS", dest="cols",
                   help="number of columns per page in the document (default: 2)")

    g = p.add_argument_group('Options controlling output format')
    allsects = ["highlights", "comments", "nits"]
    g.add_argument("-s", "--sections", metavar="SEC", nargs="*",
                   choices=allsects, default=allsects,
                   help=("sections to emit (default: %s)" % ', '.join(allsects)))
    g.add_argument("--no-group", dest="group", default=True, action="store_false",
                   help="emit annotations in order, don't group into sections")
    g.add_argument("--print-filename", dest="printfilename", default=False, action="store_true",
                   help="print the filename when it has annotations")
    g.add_argument("-w", "--wrap", metavar="COLS", type=int,
                   help="wrap text at this many output columns")

    return p.parse_args()


def main():
    args = parse_args()

    global COLUMNS_PER_PAGE
    COLUMNS_PER_PAGE = args.cols

    for file in [open(r"C:\Users\jezequiel\Desktop\Timeline.pdf", "rb")]:
        (annots, outlines) = process_file(file, args.progress)

        pp = PrettyPrinter(outlines, args.wrap)

        if args.printfilename and annots:
            print("# File: '%s'\n" % file.name)

        if args.group:
            pp.printall_grouped(args.sections, annots, args.output)
        else:
            pp.printall(annots, args.output)

    return 0
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you @Justin. I might be greedy here, by any way I can temporarily hard coded the path within the code (i.e., py file). It is quite troublesome to re-run the script from the command prompt.

Comment: I tried something like:     p.add_argument('D:\abc.pdf', type=argparse.FileType("rb"),
                   help="PDF files to process", nargs='+'), however, it seem the script required input from me.

Comment: Simpler to create a Windows batch file with `python pdfannots.py C:\abc.pdf` and run that batch file when you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The reason why I am so interested to hard coded it to ease debugging/understand the whole code using Pycharm debugging tools.

Comment: Thanks for the time taken improving further your answer, really appreciate it. However, the new suggestion above lead to the following error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'seek'. 
To avoid this, the file need to be open in rb. The line following line can be added at the beginning of the for loop  'file = open(file, 'rb')'

Comment: Good catch; I did not test it as I did not want to run some random code on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

You add the argument to a parser:

```
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("input", metavar="INFILE", type=argparse.FileType("rb"),
               help="PDF files to process", nargs='+')
args = p.parse_args()
```

Then `args.input` will be a tuple of one or more open file handles.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Chepner. But, I still unsure where should I point the pdf path. Appreciate if you provide some insight.